# 'NPM install' command installing the latest version of the libraries and not the version mentioned in the packges.json file

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

For downloading the dependencies in Angular project, I ran `npm install` in cmd at project level folder. It seems this command is installing the latest version of the libraries and not the version mentioned in the package.json file. When I searched about the command it says this will download the version from packages.json. Does someone know about this?

E.g.
In package.json version `@angular/animations": "^4.0.0"` and it downloaded  `@angular/animations@4.4.6`

My Node version-6.11.3 and npm version-3.10.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the exact package version, remove the caret in front of the package number e.g

```
 @angular/animations": "4.0.0"
```

You can find further info here http://nodesource.com/blog/semver-tilde-and-caret/